# In which way are these two PowerPoint Shapes different (accessed via API)

Tags: python, powerpoint

As part of an open source assistive technology project ([here](https://hackaday.io/project/15567-the-open-voice-factory)), I am accessing a PowerPoint file by python API ([python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

Some shapes are causing exceptions when I look at color. But it's hard to see which.

I've created this minimal example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5z22lqwb66jemq/forUpload.pptx?dl=0

and indeed, here's a screenshot:

[image]

It consists of a single slide, with shapes that work on the left, and shapes that fail on the right. Using the format painter will make a shape work (or not, depending on the source of the formatting) but I've been through every way of checking the formats that I can think of, and both sets of shapes appear identical.

How are the two sets of shapes in the minimal example different?

(for those who might be interested from a API point of view.  The line that causes the problem is:

```
self.colours[co][ro] = shape.fill.fore_colour.rgb
```

which is in https://github.com/joereddington/TheOpenVoiceFactory/blob/master/grab_text.py

and the exception is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "grab_text.py", line 374, in <module>
    grids = extract_grid(prs)   File "grab_text.py", line 353, in extract_grid
    grids.append(Grid(prs, slide, gridSize))   File "grab_text.py", line 119, in __init__
    self.process_shape(shape)   File "grab_text.py", line 164, in process_shape
    ro] = shape.fill.fore_color.rgb   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pptx/dml/fill.py", line 43, in fore_color
    return self._fill.fore_color   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pptx/dml/fill.py", line 161, in fore_color
    raise TypeError(tmpl) TypeError: a transparent (background) fill has no foreground color
```

)

Comment: There are four slides in the example. Which one corresponds to your description of work on left, fail on right?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you doing when you get the exception and what is the full stack trace?

Comment: @scanny , Apologies, wrong link. I've also added some code related stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call:

```
shape.fill.solid()
```

before attempting to access the `fore_color` attribute.

A fill can have several types, each of which have a different attribute set. The `.fore_color` attribute is particular to a solid fill. By default, the fill is transparent (i.e. None).

A little more about it in the documentation here:
http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/autoshapes.html#fill

Comment: Worked - I'd make a slight edit to the answer tho - it's a little counter-intuitive that the call has to be made before a read, rather than a write... :)